# how to change address back to old address

Tags: bitcoin-core

i set up bitcoin core wallet and had an address. I had someone pay me into this wallet. unfortunately, my mobile crashed and when I re-installed - i got a new address and lost my bitcoins on the old address. 
how can i recover?

Comment: You need a backup of the wallet.dat file from your original installation.  If you don't have one, your coins are lost.